# How to change uppercase letters of my file name to lower case?

Tags: filenames, rename

Which command change uppercase letters of file name in a directory to lower case? Thank you

I have files

```
F1
F2
FILE1
FILE2
```

I would like to rename them:

```
f1
f2
file1
file2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### For all (non-hidden) files in the current directory

In the `zsh` shell, you can do:

```
autoload zmv # best in ~/.zshrc
zmv '*' '${(L)f}'
```

(`zmv` aborts if there are any conflict (like both a `FILE` and `File` files in the current directory) before doing any rename).

(change `*` to `*(#q^/)` to only rename non-directory files, or `*(#q-^/)` for non-directory files after symlink resolution)

With `mmv`:

```
mmv '*' '#l1'
```

(`mmv` will not rename directories (even symlinks to directories) unless passed the `-r` option)

With perl's `rename` utility or any variant thereof (sometimes called `prename`):

```
rename '$_ = lc $_' ./*
```

`zmv`, `mmv` and (some variants of) `rename` have a `-n` option for *dry-run* and `-v` *verbose* option to show what is being done.

Some variants of `rename` will only translate ASCII letters. Some others, like `mmv` will treat the input as UTF-8 regardless of the locale. `zmv` will correctly translate according to the locale like the other approaches below.

In the `bash` shell:

```
for f in *[[:upper:]]*; do
  # [ -f "$f" ] || continue # uncomment to skip non-regular files if needed
  # [ -L "$f" ] && continue # uncomment to also skip symlinks even
                            # if they resolve to regular files
  mv -i -- "$f" "${f,,}"
done
```

(`-i` to ask before overwriting a file, but at the time of each rename; some `mv` implementations support a `-v` *verbose* options to show what is being done. The GNU implementation has a `-T` option which you'd also want to use here to avoid `mv FOO foo` to become *move FOO into the foo directory* if there's a `foo` directory in the current directory).

In the `ksh`, `zsh` and `bash` shells:

```
typeset -l f
for F in *[[:upper:]]*; do
  # [ -f "$f" ] || continue # uncomment to skip non-regular files if needed
  # [ -L "$f" ] && continue # uncomment to also skip symlinks even
                            # if they resolve to regular files
  f=$F
  mv -i -- "$F" "$f"
done
```

(`pdksh` and derivatives only translate ASCII letters though)

POSIXly (and assuming file names don't end in newline characters):

```
tolower() {
  awk 'BEGIN{print tolower(ARGV[1])}' "$1"
}
for f in *[[:upper:]]*; do
  # [ -f "$f" ] || continue # uncomment to skip non-regular files if needed
  # [ -L "$f" ] && continue # uncomment to also skip symlinks even
                            # if they resolve to regular files
  mv -i -- "$f" "$(tolower "$f")"
done
```

Some `awk` implementations like `mawk` only translate ASCII letters.

### Recursively (also renaming files in sub-directories)

(you may still want to read the previous section about caveats and considerations most of which apply here as well)

zsh's `zmv`:

```
zmv '(**/)(*)' '$1${(L)2}'
```

If there's a great number of files, you can speed it up by running `zmodload zsh/files` beforehand which will enable a built-in version of `mv` (used by `zmv` to actually do the renaming).

`mmv` (only renaming non-directories):

```
mmv ';*' '#1#l2'
```

With `find` and `perl`'s `rename`  (also renaming hidden files and files in hidden dirs):

```
find . -depth -name '*[[:upper:]]*' -exec rename '
  s:[^/]+\Z:\L$&:' {} +
```

POSIXly (also renaming hidden files and files in hidden dirs):

```
find . -depth -name '*[[:upper:]]*' -exec sh -c '
  for f do
    dir=${f%/*}
    name=${f##*/}
    newname=$(awk "BEGIN{print tolower(ARGV[1])}" "$name")
    mv -i -- "$f" "$dir/$newname"
  done' sh {} +
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Stéphane, your bash solution works but the only problem is that will also operate on directories and links which may not be wanted. It's be fine if it can be confirmed the directly contains only files but if not, it may have unintended results.

Comment: @NasirRiley, directories are one of many types of files, the OP didn't say they wanted to exclude any given type of file. I've added some commented out code to show how to exclude a given type of file.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I was only saying that it can't be determined that the questionner didn't literally mean only files and not directories or links where they don't want the case to change. The additions to your code account for that so it's satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

One alternative would be to use `rename - Perl extension for renaming multiple files`.

To translate all filenames to lowercase: `rename 'y/A-Z/a-z/' *`

If you do not want to install that, you could just:

```bash
for item in *; do
  mv "$item" "${item,,}" 
done
```

Comment: Both approaches have already been given in my answer (with `rename '$_ = lc $_'` to avoid limiting to A-Z letters, and `./*` to avoid problems with filenames starting with `-` in some variants of `rename`; same of `mv -i -- ...`)